# Converting protobufs enums in go

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

I have two protocol buffers, X and Y as defined below:

```
message X {
   string value1 = 1;

   enum Status {
      STATUS_UNSPECIFIED = 0;
      ACTIVE = 1;
      DELETED = 2;
   }
   Status status = 2;
}
```

---

```
message Y {
   string value2 = 1;

   enum Status {
      STATUS_UNSPECIFIED = 0;
      ACTIVE = 1;
      DELETED = 2;
   }
   Status status = 2;
}
```

I have an instance of `X`, say `x`. How can I assign `x.status` to a new `y.status` of type `Y` easily in Go?

Comment: Do you have to define the `Status` twice, or can you just define it outside the `message`s?

Comment: @Thomas, I do not have control to modify the defined protos.

Comment: Have a look at the generated code. There's probably a way to turn enums into ints and back again. Otherwise, you can always serialize the field using one type, then deserialize using the other: the wire format will be the same for both.